# Qt C++ WebKit windowCloseRequested Signal

Tags: c++, qt4, webkit, signals, slots

I am trying to connect QWebpage::windowCloseRequested() to a slot that just prints out a debug message. When I call window.close(); in JavaScript it doesn't bubble the signal up or call the slot...

```
connect(webView->page(), SIGNAL(windowCloseRequested()),this, SLOT(windowCloseRequested()));
```

The slot is setup, it is in my window.h file as a slot like this:

```
public slots:
void windowCloseRequested();
```

And the function is defined as:

```
void MyWindow::windowCloseRequested(){
  qDebug() << "I was called";
}
```

When I compile, there are no errors, there were before saying I had the slots wrong, I figured that part out, no more error, but now when I click a link, or call window.close() with javascript in a loaded webpage, it doesn't do anything. If I manually call the function, it prints out the debug message.

Any pointers, or help/solutions would be appreciated. Note, this code above is based on the Tabwidget.cpp code for a browser example. It's the best reference I could find.

Comment: What happens when you close the window manually?

Comment: It closes, without error or complaint. That is, when I click the X icon on the top right of the header bar, it closes as expected.

Comment: I answered my own question, I was being dense, but I will leave it up for future reference as the code works, and the answer is a helpful reminder to take a break and come back to it later. Unless others disagree, in which case I will delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching an onclick to an `<a>` tag is ... questionable. Use a span, and blammo, it works. This is why you should take breaks when coding, or else you make really dumb mistakes that waste time.